# Finding biconnected components (cut vertices) with a special property of a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I'd like to find vertices of a directed graph such that it divides the graph into (at least) two in a special way. The successors of a vertex must be only reachable from its predecessors through the specified vertex.

Let me illustrate. Here's a directed graph with all edges directed towards from left to right.

```
Z      C - D - E
      /   /
A - B - F - G
 \
  H - I
```

Disregarding root and leaf vertices and the isolated vertex $Z$ that trivially fit the criteria, the vertices that I'm looking for are: $B$, $D$ and $H$.

For a graph containing cycles:

```
      3 - 4 - 6
     /     \
1 - 2 <---- 5
```

The vertices I'm looking for are $2$ and $4$. $2$ is the waypoint for access from $1$, and $4$ restricts access to $6$. When it comes to other vertices in the cycle, each could fit the criteria, but as in the case for leaves and roots above, I'm not really interested in them. I would *prefer* if they were left out, but having them fit is not the worst thing in the world.

Here's my attempt at understanding the properties of such vertices. [Biconnected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) or cut vertices of a graph determine the vertices whose removal increases the number of connected components. This is too broad of a property, since vertices like $F$ that leave one unconnected component are included but its successor $D$ can be reached through $C$. Conversely, requiring a vertex to only contain [bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)) as outgoing edges is too strict, since in $B$ the later vertices form a diamond shape.

In my experience often it's simply a matter of finding a name for the thing I'm looking for. So if one exists, what is it? If not, could there be an elegant way of formulating the property I've described, without requiring an implementation to loop through the graph a bunch.

Comment: Is your graph always cycle-free?

Comment: @NikoWielopolski Thanks! Good question, since I didn't include it in the example. No, it can have self-connected vertices, and both cycles as an undirected graph and cycles as the original directed graph. Do you think that cycles introduce other special cases?

Comment: I think that the question requires further details if we allow directed cycles. Consider a directed graph on 5 vertices having edges 0->1, 1->2, 2->3, 3->1, 2->4 and set 0 to be the root. While vertex 3 is only reachable from 0 through vertex 2, there exists a walk to the vertex 4 going through 3, i.e. 0 1 2 3 1 2 4. Which vertices in that graph are the ones you are looking for?

Comment: @NikoWielopolski I edited the post with a similar example. Is that example what you were looking for? Does it clarify the problem sufficiently?

Comment: I am not exactly sure why the vertex 2 is not one of the vertices you are looking for, as all the paths from 1 (which I believe is the root here) to other vertices go through 2. Actually, I would think that all the vertices in the second example satisfy your condition.

Comment: @NikoWielopolski Oh that's right! At least for 2. I'm sorry, I haven't got the most rigorous definitions. I'll try to think about each vertex in the cycle and then I'll edit once more.

Comment: @NikoWielopolski Edited, and hopefully my ambiguity isn't too much of a problem. I don't mind the whole cycle being included in the suitable vertices, but for my purposes it would be clearer if they were left out, like leaves and roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt. It was quite self-evident, almost said in the question, but here it is.

On a similarly connected undirected graph, we remove each vertex one at a time. For that vertex to fit the criteria, each direct predecessor must be unconnected with each direct successor.

This criteria also leaves bare cycles out, which was what I wanted. By also requiring that a vertex *has* predecessors and successors, roots and leaves are left out as well.

Implementing such criteria seems to be possible quite elegantly by determining the connected components of the undirected graph after deleting the vertex. Each component must never simultaneously contain a vertex from the set of predecessor vertices and a vertex from the set of successor vertices.